# Different ways of implementing relationship between tables in oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have seen ,implementing the relation between "States"  and "Districts" in two ways:

The relation between States and Districts is one to many relationship respectively..

First way:

---

In this implementaion,take two tables "States" and "Districts" and implement the one to   many relationship between States to District as put the foreign key in Districts table.

```
 In my   "States" table the columns are:  state_id(pk) &  state_name.

 In my   "Districts" table the columns are:  district_id(pk)  district_name   state_id(fk).
```

Second Way:

---

```
  In this implementaion,take two tables "States" and "Districts" and implement the one to   many relationship between States to District as creating  the third table  "state_district" and implementing as follows.
```

In my   "States" table the columns are:  state_id(pk) &  state_name.

In my   "Districts" table the columns are:  district_id(pk)  district_name .

The third table is "state_district",the columns are s_did(pk), district_id(fk),state_id(fk).

What is the difference betwen these two mechanisms.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that in the first case there can be only one state per district, wheras in the second there can be many states per district.

Which one you should use depends entirely on whether a district can be associated with multiple states or not. If they can then you have to use the second many-to-many model. If they cannot then while in practice you *could* use the second model, it would be incorrect to do so -- you should use the first one-to-many model.

Answer (score 2):

for one to many relationship we use a table's primary key as foreign key in another table - Which is your first approach ans correct in this case

For many to many relationship we use a third table to store the relationship between first 2 tables- which is not required in your case as state to district has one to many relationship

Comment: If i use second way,Is there any drawbacks or disadvantages.

Comment: the disadvantage is that you will need to maintain another table . So if you can do something in two tables then why to create another one. your second approach will not give any wrong data and will exhibit the same one to many relation but increase your maintenance activity

Comment: Hmm, you might want to look into normalization before we start talking about the "disadvantage of maintaining other tables"

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between these two mechanisms.

The difference is that the second method *allows* a district to be associated with more than one state. You can do this by just adding another row for a given district in the third table.

```
INSERT INTO state_district (district_id, state_id) VALUES
 (1234, 49), (1234, 50);
```

Now you have the same district 1234 associated with both Alaska (49) and Hawaii (50).

I would assume you *don't* really need this. In fact, it would be better to ensure that each district belongs to exactly one state. You should have only a one-to-many relationship between states and districts. So you should use the first design.

Answer (score 1):

Your second way should be done if there is a many to many relationship between states to districts.

You first way is correct and you should implement.

Comment: but with second way also,they implemented one to many relationship. whats the difference.

Comment: it is merely unnecessary creation of a third "entity" when in reality it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose the following table structures:

```
States: --don't need extra metadata such as the sequence generated value  
state_name varchar2(50) PRIMARY KEY

Districts:  -- don't need extra metadata
district_name varchar2(100) PRIMARY KEY

State_Districts
state_name varchar2(50)
district_name varchar2(100)  
primary key (state_name,district_name)
```

This ensures that you don't have duplicate `district names` which are real unique identifiers, regardless of if Wyoming and Pennsylvania have the same district name, the data is independent of each other.  This also ensures that there will be no null values in any of the three tables, this is pretty important when we think about normalization techniques.

Comment: Requiring that district names be unique may be problematic if it turns out that they're unique only within a state.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Care to elaborate?  The only assumption I have made is that a district is unique for a state.  I.E.  `(PA,BERKS), (PA,BERKS)` would never occur.  `(PA,BERKS), (MD,BERKS)` is still valid and would be reflected correctly in my table

Comment: What I mean is that there can be only one "BERKS", regardless of state. Using a name as the PK on the district does not seem to be robust (in fact I wouldn't use it on State either).

Comment: @DavidAldridge I guess I am missing something here from my relational algebra classes a few years back.  If the argument is to remove both the `states` and `districts` table and only have the `state_districts` table I can see that.  If it is something else, I think I am missing your point

Answer (score 0):

It would appear from your first table definition of the two tables that there is a State ID field in the District table.  This indicates to me that there are one or more districts per state.  In this case, a third table would be redundant.